# Fetch all records from a single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I ve 3 models

`a is client`

`b is team leader`

`c is worker`

Now

`a has_many b through ab`,

`b has_many c through bc` and

`a has_many c through ac`.

`ab,bc,ac` are my join tables created by `has_many through association`

Now

`a can create b`,

`b can create c` and

`a can create c`

i.e worker can be created by both `Client` and `Team leader`.

Now i need to retrieve all the `workers` created by `client` and `TeamLeader`.
Although i can write the `if/else` condition in the controller but i want simply to get all the records from a single query?
Or should i use normal if/else condition?

Comment: are u saving created_by in worker?

Comment: no i m not saving created_by in worker model

Comment: How do you differentiate who created what?

Comment: by normal client_id.!!

Answer (score 0):

As both Client and Team Leader can have workers and Team Leader belongs to a Client.So,
I will suggest to have a single abc through table instead of ab,bc and ac as single abc join table will be less complicated to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you might need to know here:

1, For one-to-many relationship, you don't need join table. Join table is for many-to-many associations;
2, Rails use model_id( in your example, client_id) for table mapping by default. If you really need to keep a "who created whom" relationship, use "create_by" column in the worker model instead of "client_id". But I guess you only need a belongs_to relationship here, since in real world a client can't "create" a worker. :p

Also, I assume that your worker do not directly touch with client, then the client should be only able to find a worker through his/her leader. In this situation, you need:

In Model A (Client):

```
has_many :b
has_many :c, :through => :b
```

In Model B (Team leader):

```
belongs_to :a
has_many :c
```

In Model C (Worker):

```
belongs_to :b
```

In this way, you can query workers by calling a.c and b.c, it will find all workers related with certain client/team leader.

Comment: i ve not used the `one to many` relationship. These all models have `many to many` association among each other and my system is like this only that there is a need to maintain the worker created by the client and team leader belongs to same organisation